# Javascript: Regular Expression to match 8 digits, one character and one hypen in any sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I write a pattern to match any sequence of 8 digits, one character and one hyphen.

I am not very good at writing regex

I have tried `/([0-9]{8}([-]{1})([a-zA-Z]{1}))` this but it matches only specific sequence also tried like `^(([0-9]{8})([a-zA-Z]{1})([-]{1}))$` 
but it doesn't work.

So please help me to write the regex

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Look, [`^(([0-9]{8})([a-zA-Z]{1})([-]{1}))$`](https://regex101.com/r/kF0pA1/1) works as it matches `12345678a-`.

Comment: Can the digits, letter and hyphen be in any order?  Like 1234a567-8 ?

Comment: When you say "character", you mean letter?

Comment: Also, should the regex only allow specific exactly ONE letter and ONE hyphen, or could there be more than one of each? Likewise for digits, exactly 8, or could there be more? If for any of the above it can be more, is there a fixed or maximum length for the total sequence?

Comment: Please remove all these useless `{1}` quantifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the digits, letter and hyphen can appear mixed together in any order (like `1234k56-78`, use a regex like this:

```
(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*-)(?=(?:.*\d){8}).{10}
```

If the digits need to all be consecutive, then use a regex like this:

```
(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*-)(?=.*\d{8}).{10}
```

Comment: Thanks @aaron_world_traveler

Comment: for this a-a-11111111 string expression 1 giving problem

Comment: Your post says one character and one hyphen.  You have two of each there.

Comment: Yes I need exactly one character between [a-zA-z] and exactly one hyphen and 8 digits if string not matches this then it must fail

Comment: If you want the pattern to match the full string only, then put ^ at the front of the pattern and $ at the end.

Comment: @aaron_world_traveler -  can you please explain the syntax? I thought that `.` in `.{10}` or `.*` will match ANY character. How does this work? why do you need double `?=` for the digits? why do you need the final `{10}`?

Comment: @HananShteingart - you are correct, the dot matches any character, and so `.{10}` matches any ten characters.  This works here because of the lookahead assertions before it.  The OP's post is looking for exactly ten characters, no more, no less, so that's why it is explicitly specified.  The lookahead assertions simply make sure that the ten characters contain exactly one letter, one hyphen, and eight digits, all in any order.  Does that explanation help?

Comment: Thank @aaron_world_traveler, still I don't understand the syntax. Why doesn't it look for any 10 character following the `(...)` expression? Why is there an AND operation between the `(...)` and the following `.{10}` ? Moreover, why doesn't it care on the order of the internal brackets? I guess my problem is the pattern `(pattern1)(pattern2)(pattern3).{n}`

Comment: I would suggest reading up on lookahead assertions, that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

```
s = "1239123-a4";
doesitmatch = s.split('').sort().join('').match(/^-[0-9]{8}[a-zA-Z]$/);
```

This sorts the string in a way that makes matching easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this `/(\d{8}-\w)/g`

> \d{8} match a digit [0-9]
>   Quantifier: {8} Exactly 8 times
>   - matches the character - literally
>   \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]

The `( )` are there if you want to capture the matched substring.

**Example**

```js
var str = 'sdsqdsq12348567-adsqds56871239-qdsqs';
var out = str.match(/\d{8}-\w/g);

document.write('<pre>' + out.join('\n') + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This won't work, as it only matches when the digits come first.  It also allows for an underscore.

Comment: Or not, see my example. `_` is a character.

Comment: The OP's regex example attempts clearly show he is trying to get exactly 8 digits, a letter, and a hyphen, in various orders.

Comment: The first attempt shows an order and he's talking about a "sequence", a sequence has a specific order, he gave it.

Comment: Look again, he's trying to match at least two possible sequence orders.  One is digits then letter then hyphen, another is digits then hyphen then letter.

Comment: You're right, maybe he's confused? The word "sequence" carries less doubt but let's see what he means exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this puzzle and regex for this is

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[-])(?=(?:.*\d){8}).{10}$
```

which will strictly follow all conditions

Thanks for Helping me

Comment: And your {1}'s are not needed.

Comment: Instead of posting your own answer, you should have accepted that of @aaron_world_traveler.